# Paste list to an Excel file

Tags: python, excel, list

I have a list with words and a number next to it, so every item in the list looks like this:

```
mylist = ['dog 2', 'cat 14']
```

I need to arrange the list by whichever item has the largest number next to it, then paste the list to an Excel or CSV and save it.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use key parameter in sorted function to sort by the number after ' '(space)

```
list=['dog 2','cat 14']
```

create a new list which is in format:
list2 = [[dog, 2], [cat,14]]

```
list2 = []
for i in list:
    i = i.split(' ')
    i[1] = int(i[1])
    list2.append(i)
```

sort list 2

```
list = sorted(list2, key=lambda element: element[1], reverse = True)
```

write to a csv file saperated by ','. and ending with '\n'

```
file = open('filename.csv', 'w')
for element in list:
    file.write("%s,%d\n" % (element[0], element[1]))
file.close
```

this will generate a file named filename.csv which looks like:

```
cat,14
dog,2
```

Comment: where would that file be after i ran the program??

Comment: put all the code in a file named, createcsv.py. then run $ python createcsv.py, you'll get the file in the same directory as createcsv.py. Try it and tell me if it works for you..

Answer (score 1):

Sorting part, you can do like this:

```
>>> my_list=['dog 2','cat 14']
>>> my_list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split()[1]), reverse=True)
>>> 
>>> my_list
['cat 14', 'dog 2']
```

If you can have multiple non-numeric words before the numeric value, then you can given index `-1` instead of `1`:

```
>>> my_list=['dog 2','cat 14', 'cat eat mouse 15']
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[-1]), reverse=True)
['cat eat mouse 15', 'cat 14', 'dog 2']
```